# How to rebase from a branch with a changing commit?

Tags: git

Initially I started like this:

```
Branch A:    
  Commit A1  
  Commit M9

Branch B:   
  Commit B1  
  Commit M9
```

Then I did:

```
git checkout B
git rebase A
```

I ended up with:

```
Branch A:    
  Commit A1
  Commit M9

Branch B:   
  Commit B1  
  Commit A1
  Commit M9
```

Then I did:

```
git checkout A
// then I modified the branch and then I did
git commit -a --amend
```

Now the state of my branches is

```
Branch A:    
  Commit A1
  Commit M9

Branch B:   
  Commit B1  
  Commit A1
  Commit M9

Note that now Commit A1 is actually different in both branches.
```

How can I update `Branch B` with the new `Commit A1` that is in `Branch A`?

Comment: You need to rebase again.

Comment: That fails miserably. Tons of conflicts

Comment: If your `old A1 → new A1` and `old A1 → B1` change the common part differently, you are out of luck and have to resolve the conflicts :(

Comment: Ah that's unfortunate I was hoping for some git magic but I guess that makes sense I'm outa luck!

Comment: You can also use interactive rebase to delete `A1` on Branch B, and then do the rebase again.

Comment: @merlin2011 it won't be possible if B1 is based on the changes introduced in A1. The solution is to do the 2 things in the same time. What I suggest in my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a :

```
git checkout B
git rebase -i A
```

and when your text editor opened, remove the line corresponding to the 'old A1' commit (which is in the branch B).

Normally, you should not have conflicts to handle, except if B1 is based on same piece of codes that you changed in your amend (but it should be a lot easier to handle) .